# What's the relationship between "Fehler" and "Befehl"?

Tags: etymology

The two seem to have pretty different meanings, one meaning a mistake and the other meaning an order. The usual "be- as transitive marker" explanation doesn't really seem to help here either. What could be going on?

Comment: keep it simple and ask what's happening with the verbs *befehlen* and *fehlen*. I don't think you need to go to the substantives.

Comment: @c.p. what would be the difference if we were checking the relationship between the verbs or the substantives? also, the meaning is a different one :(

Comment: @Vogel612 oh, there is a difference: the prefix *be-* making some verbs transitive (which is what the OP supposes as an inconsistency or strange case or whatever) is, well, precisely for verbs.

Comment: Usually it's a mistake to follow orders ;) .. sorry, had to

Answer (score 14):

According to the respective DWDS-articles for [fehlen](http://dwds.de/?view=1&qu=fehlen) und [befehlen](http://dwds.de/?qu=befehlen), both word have no common etymology.

`befehlen` is derived from Old High German *bifelahan* (to entrust, to bury).

`fehlen` is derived from Middle High German *vælen* (to miss, to fail), which is a loanword from Old French *falir* (to miss, to fail, to be amiss).

They only look similar because of phonetic developments and standardization of German.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't any relationship.

Comment: Welcome to [german.se]! while your answer may be correct it would really be nice if you could add some more explanation on **why** that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

`Befehl` means `Command`; `Fehler` means `Error`. Except both words are German and norm, I'm afraid there is no any other obvious similarity.